# Innosetup Create Folders in Application directory

Tags: inno-setup

Hej guys!
I am trying to make a installer for my application with innosetup, everything goes finde, just a little problem:
It does not create the directorys i put in

```
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\data\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\Media\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

It just puts all files of the directorys in the application folder but does not create the directorys and put the files into them.
Do you know how to make it realy CREATE the folder and put the files into him?

Here my whole code:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Fower"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "FoxFire Development"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.foxfiredev.net"
#define MyAppExeName "Fower.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{1D8512EB-BA40-41B9-8E38-262D637508B9}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputDir=C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\FowerSetup
OutputBaseFilename=FowerSetup
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\FoxFireDev\Projekt - Fower\ManagementNeu\Release\icon.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "german"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\Fower.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\data\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\Media\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\icon.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\libsndfile-1.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\msvcp110.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\msvcr110.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\openal32.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\sansation.ttf"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\sfgui wqeq.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\sfgui.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\sfml-audio-2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\sfml-graphics-2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\sfml-network-2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\sfml-system-2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\sfml-window-2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\tgui.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\thor.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: That should not happen. You are using correct flags for those entries and the files are actually copied in the same folder structure as their source (I've just tested it in Inno Setup 5.5.4 (u) for being sure).

Answer (score 3):

you can change the code as follows to copy the contents seperately in respective folders ,

```
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\data\*"; DestDir: "{app}\data"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\Etix\Desktop\Fower\Media\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Media"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using the `[Dirs]` section to get `{app}\data` and `{app}\Media` created first?

Comment: Are you aware that application directories are created by the same function as those created for the `[Dirs]` section ?

Comment: Yes, I am. However, combining the two [Dirs] directories with beginner's answer should do the trick.

Comment: Why, if directories created for the `[Files]` entries are created the same way as those for `[Dirs]` ? You would be doing the same thing twice.